# Para que serve o AS no Python?

Tags: python

Por favor alguém me ajude em relação a isso.Me explicando o porque, para que e como funciona o AS no Python.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

É como se você estivesse dando um apelido a algo, por exemplo `except Exception as E`, ou, `import serial as ser`.

Pois as vezes é muito mais fácil você apelidar algo do que ter que escrever o nome dela várias vezes, imagina por exemplo ter que escrever `matplotlib.pyplot` toda vez que for trabalhar com gráficos, é muito mais fácil apelidar ela de 'plt', do que ter que escrever ela inteira toda a santa vez que for usa-la.

Comment: Obrigado por me responder.